# Premeditated Notifications

Tags: ios, notificationcenter

Is it possible to setup an app to send notifications from it's self at specified times? Perhaps by putting them in a queue? As of now I'm having to go through a push notification server and that seems like over kill when I'm sending messages out every Tuesday morning. Also, what is this called (so I can better research it on the web)

Comment: UILocalNotification should be a start!

Comment: So you want your app to just pop up a message say at 8:00am every Tuesday? Does this have to pop up when the user is not in the app as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can schedule notification like this:

```
- (void)scheduleNotification
{
    //Cancel all previous Local Notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    //Set new Local Notifications
    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls != nil)
    {
        UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
        //3 days
        notif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:60.0f*60.0f*24.0f*3.0f sinceDate:[NSDate date]];
        notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notif.alertBody = @"Come Back Again! Lets blast All Zombie!";
        notif.alertAction = @"PLAY";
        notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
        }    
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];

    [self scheduleNotification];
    ..
}
```